# "With the" Does one pronounce both "th" sounds?

Tags: pronunciation, connected-speech

Take the random sentence "Start with the basics." Would you pronounce both "th" sounds separately or link them essentially saying "withe". Being a non native speaker I find pronouncing both difficult without disrupting the "flow of speech" which is often stated as being very important when speaking english.

Comment: How quickly are you speaking?

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends on the region whether or not someone will say both "th" sounds or not. I'm American and from the Pacific Northwest, and I tend to merge the two words into sounding like this:

> Start **wi-thuh** basics.

As with most languages (I'm sure), people are lazy, and sounds will tend to mesh together if they're similar enough. But as I said, it probably depends on who you ask whether or not those words are said separately or not.

Comment: Other dialects might say something more like "wit/wid-the" or "wi'-the" (indicating a glottal stop) as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's just one sound, unless you are speaking really slowly.

Comment: I'd put it the other way round; it's a long consonant, unless I'm speaking very quickly. What it isn't is two separate consonant sounds.

Comment: Ah, yes, I forgot that point.